# Sending pdf from static resources as attachment in visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce-component

I am trying to add pdf from static resources to my Visual force email template attachment tag. VF email template which will be used by a workflow.I was able to render a image file from static resource as pdf, but how do I get an existing  pdf as pdf attachment in email template.
apex:page tag are not vaild in email template.
Also I tried reading he pdf body in a controller but it is not in readable format.

Please let me know how do I attach the pdf from static resources in visual force email template

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution. First I read the static resource PDF in a blob and attached that blob with the email. I hope this will help.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setUseSignature(false);
email.setSaveAsActivity(true);
email.setSubject('Email using Apex');
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com'};
email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
email.setHtmlBody('<html><body>Hi <b>Saroj</b></body></html>');
StaticResource sr = [Select  s.Name, s.Id, s.Body From StaticResource s where s.Name = 'static_resource']; // 'static_resource' is the name of the static resource PDF.
Blob tempBlob = sr.Body;
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
efa.setBody(tempBlob);
efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] emailList = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email};
Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you already success render PDF page, so I assume you have Visualforce that render as PDF.In this code I named it as PDF_VF.So I attached the VisualForce page into Messaging.EmailFileAttachment.

```
 PageReference pdfPlan=Page.PDF_VF;
Blob bPlan= pdfPlan.getContent();
 Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] attachments= new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {};
            Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
            efa.setFileName('PDF_Attachment'.pdf');
            efa.setBody(bPlan);
            attachments.add(efa);
```

Comment: Sorry but I didnot get what you said, previouly I had tried send a image from static resource as pdf attachment. But now I want to send a existing pdf  as pdf attachment through my vf email template.

Comment: <messaging:attachment renderAs="pdf" filename="Testsample.pdf">
  <html>
     <body >
     <apex:outputText value="{!$Resource.mypdf}"/>
      <apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!$Resource.mypdf}">
          {!$Resource.mypdf}
        </apex:outputPanel>     <apex:sectionHeader title="test" subtitle="test1" help="{!$Resource.mypdf}" />
     </body>
    </html>
  </messaging:attachment>

Comment: Given above is my attachment tag in VF email template. but I only get the partial link of pdf in the attachment.

Comment: You can paste your code in your question for better view.Surround your code with {}.