# Dynamic Attachment in Visual Force Template

Tags: workflow

I have upload the file name  as Condizioni_generali_di_vendita.pdf in static resource name called TC_for_Italy, I have created the Visual force page template for email sending the attachment of static Resource

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <p><br>Please find the attachment of Order Confirmation and Terms  Conditions documents {!relatedTo.id}</br></p>

        <center>
        {!$User.Username}

        </center>

    </body>

        </html>
     </messaging:htmlEmailBody>

      <messaging:attachment renderAs="PDF">
      <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Attachments}" var="a"/>
      <apex:includescript value="(!$staticResourcename.TC_for_Italy}"/>
      </messaging:attachment>
    </messaging:emailTemplate>
```

**The above template in Email alert in workflow rule the attachment of static resource file is not going through email,Please help me for sending the Static resource attachment in email alert,what i have made Mistake,Please Guide Me**

Comment: When you create email template you get option to link a file as attachment why don't you just use that?

Comment: @TusharSharma i dont want link , i want the file to send in email, attachment file is going,static Resource file is not going, guide me for that

Comment: When I say link I means you can attach a file directly. Why don't you just use that.

Comment: @TusharSharma if you are providing the link, link only going through the mail, then you have to download the link and the file, guide for static resource attachment file, my requirement is like that

Comment: @TusharSharma Possible or not

Comment: @user36188 It is probably possible. But will take some effort. You need to write code to send out this email and convert the pdf file into a blob and add that blob into your email. You need to consider whether it is worthwhile though

Comment: this is the only solution I guess https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008nwbIAA

Comment: @Ratan,@lanceshi sorry static resource file is pdf only

Comment: @user36188 check the solution given in the link. so instead of sending email from workflow. You can just update any field on the record that will fire the trigger and from trigger you can send the email with static resource pdf as attachment

Comment: @ratan normal attachment file is going, why static resource file is not going can you justify about static resource attachment pdf not going

Comment: @user36188 When ratan says normal file, it means the file generated by Visualforce tags. Not a file on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

The related question is here: [Sending pdf from static resources as attachment in visualforce email template](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82963/sending-pdf-from-static-resources-as-attachment-in-visualforce-email-template)

I will let you decide it is worthwhile to use this method or not. Basically, you need to convert the static resource into a blob and send the email via code. This can also be viewed as an extension to Ratan's solution - you have to use code to send it out anyway.

The code in the previous post:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setUseSignature(false);
email.setSaveAsActivity(true);
email.setSubject('Email using Apex');
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com'};
email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
email.setHtmlBody('<html><body>Hi <b>Saroj</b></body></html>');
StaticResource sr = [Select  s.Name, s.Id, s.Body From StaticResource s where s.Name = 'static_resource']; // 'static_resource' is the name of the static resource PDF.
Blob tempBlob = sr.Body;
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
efa.setBody(tempBlob);
efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] emailList = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email};
Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);
```

Whether the static resource file is pdf or not doesn't matter. You can set the file name in your code.

Comment: where  i have to replace the code with the above vf template  @Lance shi

Comment: @user36188 Probably in your trigger. It depends when do you trigger your email sending. But since you originally put it in email alert, so now it is probably in the trigger.

Comment: it is not possible directly in  email alert in  Visual force template @lanceshi

Comment: @user36188 I don't think so. At least according to all of us' current investigation, no.